# What do I need to do in order to use CMake from a custom directory?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've installed a version of CMake to `/some/where/cmake`, and have put `/some/where/cmake/bin` in the `PATH`.

What environment variables do I need to set, and what other actions do I need to take, in order for my custom CMake to function properly? Specifically, how do I ensure it looks in `/some/where/cmake/share` before `/usr/share` for CMake-related files?

Notes:

- The OS is GNU/Linux.
- I'm using CMake 3.16.6.
- If I issue the CMake command `message(STATUS ${CMAKE_ROOT})`, I get: `/some/where/cmake/share/cmake-3.16`

Comment: Can you create a file with `message(STATUS ${CMAKE_ROOT})` and run it with `cmake -P`? That will tell you what CMake thinks its root is.

Comment: @Botje: I can do whatever you suggest. Please provide instructions making no assumptions other than the ones I've indicated.

Comment: _Please_ create a file with those contents and run it with `cmake -P` so we know what CMake thinks its root is. I want to make sure CMake is looking in the wrong directory before we spend time trying to change the search path. If it is looking in the correct place, you have a different problem and we need to debug _that_. A quick test suggests that `cmake` computes a path relative to the binary for `CMAKE_ROOT`.

Comment: @Botje: See edit, and thanks.

Comment: So CMake will look for modules in the directory where you wanted it to. So is there any remaining problem?

Comment: @Botje: I don't know, that's why I asked...

Comment: I suggest you try something and see, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What environment variables do I need to set, and what other actions do I need to take, in order for my custom CMake to function properly? Specifically, how do I ensure it looks in /some/where/cmake/share before /usr/share for CMake-related files?

**Nothing!** CMake is designed to look relative to the binary's actual location on your filesystem and otherwise ignore standard system directories for its own functioning (of course it will detect these for toolchain purposes).

I have personally installed CMake 3.1 -- 3.20 on Ubuntu Linux by just downloading and untarring the release archives [here](https://cmake.org/files/) to `/home/alex/bin/cmake-3.X.Y` and creating corresponding symlinks `cmake-3.X`, `ctest-3.X`, and `cpack-3.X` in `/home/alex/bin` (which is in my `PATH`). I use these regularly to test answers I post here on StackOverflow. Took all of 5 minutes to set up.